# Como fazer uma soma de duas matrizes gerando uma terceira em c#?

Tags: c#, int

Não consigo fazer, tentei usar o laço FOR e também o IF para armazenar na matriz antes de efetuar a soma, porém meu conhecimento em c# é escasso. e a matriz é uma 2x2.

Comment: O que já tentou fazer? Adicione na pergunta sua tentativa.

Comment: Aproveite e faça também o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do site para ficar a conhecer como funciona. E também de [como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

O resultado de uma soma de uma matriz de ordem 2 x 2 é a soma dos elementos correspondentes de suas posições, exemplo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>***Fonte:*** http://mundoeducacao.bol.uol.com.br/matematica/adicao-subtracao-matrizes.htm</sup>

Para codificar isso em [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), é muito simples, a declaração de uma matriz de inteiros 2 x 2 seria:

```
int[,] matrizA = new int[2, 2];
```

a atribuição em cada posição:

```
matrizA[0, 0] = 1;
matrizA[0, 1] = 2;
matrizA[1, 0] = 3;
matrizA[1, 1] = 4;
```

e a recuperação:

```
int i0 = matrizA[0, 0];
int i1 = matrizA[0, 1];
int i2 = matrizA[1, 0];
int i3 = matrizA[1, 1];
```

---

***Um exemplo minimo:***

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] matrizA = new int[2, 2];
    int[,] matrizB = new int[2, 2];

    matrizA[0, 0] = 1;
    matrizA[0, 1] = 2;
    matrizA[1, 0] = 3;
    matrizA[1, 1] = 4;

    matrizB[0, 0] = 1;
    matrizB[0, 1] = 2;
    matrizB[1, 0] = 3;
    matrizB[1, 1] = 4;

    int[,] matrizC = Sum(matrizA, matrizB);
    View(matrizC);

    System.Console.ReadKey();

}

public static int[,] Sum(int[,] a, int[,] b)
{
    int[,] result = new int[a.Rank, a.Rank];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Rank; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < a.Rank; j++)
            result[i, j] = a[i, j] + b[i, j];
    return result;
}

public static void View(int[,] a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Rank; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.Rank; j++)
            System.Console.Write("{0} ", a[i, j]);
        System.Console.WriteLine();
    }

}
```

esse [exemplo rodando ONLINE](https://ideone.com/ZbSz5f) onde o resultado esperado seria:

```
2 4 
6 8
```

nesse código o método `static` `sum` é o responsável em somar os elementos correspondentes onde o primeiro `for` é o controle de **linhas** e o segundo `for` o de **colunas**, assim até terminar **linhas** e **colunas** da matriz disponibilizada e esse método por ser executado em matriz maiores só que da mesma quantidade de elementos, exemplo: **3 x 3**, **4 x 4**, *etc*., e o método `static` `view` vai mostrar os elementos existente em uma matriz.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Classe Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Adição e Subtração de matrizes](http://mundoeducacao.bol.uol.com.br/matematica/adicao-subtracao-matrizes.htm)
- [Propriedade Array.Rank](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.array.rank(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Propriedade Array.Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx)